# Three nested for loops slow down performance

Tags: python, performance

I was wondering if there's another way to solve this question without using 3 nested for loops as I did here? I am aware that nesting loops in such a manner will most likely cause a lot of problems if the method will be tested on a list that is big enough.

> Here's the question:

```
from typing import List

def can_pay_with_three_coins(denoms: List[int], amount: int) -> bool:
    """Return True if and only if it is possible to form amount, which is a
    number of cents, using exactly three coins, which can be of any of the
    denominations in denoms.

    >>> can_pay_with_three_coins([1, 5, 10, 25], 36)
    True
    >>> can_pay_with_three_coins([1, 5, 10, 25], 37)
    False

    """
```

> Here's my solution:

```
for i in range(len(denoms)):
    one_coin = denoms[i]
    for j in range(len(denoms)):
        another_coin = denoms[j]
        for k in range(len(denoms)):
            last_coin = denoms[k]
            if one_coin + another_coin + last_coin == amount:
                return True
return False
```

I am sure that there's another way of tackling this problem, it's just that I can't really think of it. 
**Thanks for any help!**

Comment: If you have already tested (1,5,10), there is no need to test any of the following: (1,10,5), (5,1,10), (5,10,1), (10,1,5), or (10,5,1).

Comment: If the first two coins already add up to more than amount, there is no point checking anything for the third coin.

Comment: I totally forgot about this possbility. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's cheat with itertools :)

```
import itertools
from typing import List


def can_pay_with_three_coins(denoms: List[int], amount: int) -> bool:
    """Return True if and only if it is possible to form amount, which is a
    number of cents, using exactly three coins, which can be of any of the
    denominations in denoms.

    >>> can_pay_with_three_coins([1, 5, 10, 25], 36)
    True
    >>> can_pay_with_three_coins([1, 5, 10, 25], 37)
    False

    """

    for variant in itertools.permutations(denoms, len(denoms)):
        if sum(variant[:3]) == amount:
            return True

    return False


print(can_pay_with_three_coins([1, 5, 10, 25], 36))
print(can_pay_with_three_coins([1, 5, 10, 25], 37))
print(can_pay_with_three_coins([1, 1, 5, 10, 25], 37))
print(can_pay_with_three_coins([1, 3, 5, 10, 25], 37))
print(can_pay_with_three_coins([20, 20, 20, 50], 60))
```

output

```
True
False
False
False
True
```

Comment: Shouldn't  print(can_pay_with_three_coins([1, 1, 5, 10, 25], 37)) be False?  Your code has True.

Comment: The code is wrong. It fails for input `[20, 20, 20, 50], 60`, for example. That sum can obviously be paid with three coins, but your function returns `False`. A greedy algorithm such as this cannot be used to solve 3SUM.

Comment: oh, also three coins. ok, I am going to remove the answer :D Absolutely incorrect. Sorry

Comment: can't remove approved, so I've updated it using generators, they are so awesome in python! @RobKennedy ;)

Comment: Time complexity of your solution is not good yet, in case of True answer it is O(n^3) and in case of False answer it is O(n!), If you replace "len(denoms)" by 3, your time complexity will always be O(n^3) that is not better than @Flavio Esposito's solution

Answer (score 4):

This is a famous question named 3 sum.

Time complexity of this solution is O(n^3), you can implement an algorithm of O(n^2) that is explained and implemented in several languages in the link below:

[Find a triplet that sum to a given value](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-triplet-that-sum-to-a-given-value/)